# apache spark(V. 2.1) streaming java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, streaming, consumer

The below code uses source kafka, sink hdfs, using spark streaming. Any way to move commitAsync to the end ?

```
SparkSession spark = new SparkSession.Builder().appName(consumer_group).getOrCreate();
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.milliseconds(batchDurationLong));

stream =  KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(jssc, LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                ConsumerStrategies.<String, Object>Subscribe(topics, kafkaParams));

stream.transform(rddT  ->{
    OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rddT.rdd()).offsetRanges();
   ((CanCommitOffsets) stream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
    return rddT;
     }).map(
            rdd -> {
              return rdd.value().toString();
         }).foreachRDD(invrdd ->
                {
                   if (!invrdd.isEmpty()) {
                     SparkSession sparkWorker = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(invrdd.context().getConf());
                     Dataset<Row> invDataset = sparkWorker.read().option("mode", "PERMISSIVE").json(invrdd);
                     invDataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).parquet(storageDir + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
}
});
```

Comment: By the way, Kafka Connect can already write Parquet data into Hadoop

Comment: Thanks. We don't have Kafka connect set up.

Comment: It's included with Kafka 0.10 and up

Comment: Data is avro format, use confluent de-serializer, schema registry. Not sure how to use connect in the mix. Any samples ?  Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing to "set up" other than two property files. You can run `connect-standalone` from an existing Kafka server. Kafka Connect HDFS is written by Confluent. Avro from the registry is a a first class citizen. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#quickstart And Parquet output is just a configuration. https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/hdfs_connector.html#format-and-partitioner